# scrolling images in ios automatically

Tags: ios

i have multiple images in array and a scrollView all the images should scroll automatically and when i  clicked the image it should navigate to other view and display its details. after completing images scrolling from 0 to end of the array  it should Again load 1st image  i.e 0. in Animating i have lot of problem please help me....

iam using this code

```
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void) onTimer {

    // Updates the variable h, adding 100 (put your own value here!)
    h += 100; 

    //This makes the scrollView scroll to the desired position  
    yourScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, h);  

}
```

Comment: This can help you   http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html

Answer (score 0):

try [iCarousel library](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) for scrolling the images, use autoscrolling example for the reference, set wrap property to yes if you want to repeat the content in the loop. add image array to carousel and implement carousel datasource and delegate methods to scroll the images. you can change different types like linear, rotary or overflow etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can create image outlet after that

```
NSMutableArray *imgArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i =0; i<imgUrlArray.count; i++) {
        NSString *imgStr = [serviceImgArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgStr]];
        [imgArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
    }
    yourimageView.animationImages = imgArray;
    yourimageView.animationDuration = 10;
    [yourimageView startAnimating];
```

that's it.